# Use packaged hibernate version in EAR

Tags: java, hibernate, classloader, jboss-eap-7

I'm deploying my EAR on [JBoss EAP 7.0.0](https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/download/), which has the following structure:

```
app.ear
|-- ejb.jar
|-- app.war
|-- lib
     |-- hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar
     |-- hibernate-hibernate-spatial-5.2.10.Final.jar
     |-- hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
|-- META-INF
     |-- application.xml
     |-- jboss-app.xml
```

I added a small piece of code in one of my EJB bean that prints `org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString()` to know which version of Hibernate my application is using and it gives me `5.0.9.Final-readhat-1` instead of something like `5.2.10.Final`.

I've read a lot about classloading issues (especially [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossClassLoadingUseCases) and [here](https://www.protechtraining.com/bookshelf/jboss_admin_tutorial/class_loading?ncr=1)), but after many different trials, I couldn't find a way to make JBoss use the packaged version of Hibernate in my EAR.

It looks like the  tag is ignored in EAP 7 ? It seems that the classloading [has changed](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) in JBoss AS 7.

Here is the content of my jboss-app.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-app>   
  <loader-repository>  
    my.package:archive=app.ear  
    <loader-repository-config>   
    java2ParentDelegation=false  
    </loader-repository-config>  
  </loader-repository>   
</jboss-app>
```

Is there a way to force JBoss EAP 7 to load the classes from my EAR prior to the bootstrap classloader ?

Note: I also posted this question [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/275897).

======================================================= EDIT

I tried with this `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="org.hibernate" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

During the deployment, I get the following error:

```
{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"app.ear/ejb.jar#app-ejbPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"app.ear/ejb.jar#app-ejbPU\": java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JBoss 7** (and **WildFly**) is using a modules system instead of class loaders to separate different apps and libraries.

Try to disable hibernate in your app: Place a `jboss-deployment-stucture.xml` file in your EAR's `META-INF` folder:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.hibernate" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

See: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, with your suggestion the deployment of the EAR fails because the service is missing: `WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable d
ependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"app.ear/ejb.jar#app-ejbPU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.app]`

I tried to redeclare the module with the embedded classes in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` but then I got a configuration error still due to ClassLoaderIssues: `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype`

Comment: You may have all hibernate related libraries within the project's WEB-INF/lib directory. But the JBoss provided libraries caused conflicts so you have removed the content within the tag <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.hibernate"> in module.xml file available in JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\hibernate\main directory. Also you have removed the dependencies of hibernate libraries in jboss-deployment-structure.xml as,
~~~
<exclusions><module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/></exclusions>
~~~
After these changes you can able overcome the conflict issues of hibernate

Comment: The JBoss EAP 7 server has a Hibernate 5.0.x version. To use Hibernate 5.2.x you have to exclude the default Hibernate and package the correct one. see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly